# Chrome Extension : Syntax for retrieving cached data by tab.id in popup.js

Tags: javascript, css, api, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I need help understanding what the syntax would be to best send data from each individual tab from my **Content.js**, to each tab's individual report in the **Pop.js**. I'm very new to development.

I'm specifically trying to run these scripts once the page has stopped loading, and have a popup report for each tab showing that page's specific metrics. The data can be deleted from the cache on window close.

**Content.js** Runs when user navigates to page > cached in **Background.js** > user can open report in **Popup.js** by tab.id and retrieve from Cache

**Background.js:**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender) => {
    chrome.storage.local.get('counts')
        .then(data => {
            if (!data.counts) data.counts = {};
            data.counts['tab' + sender.tab.id] = request.counts;
            chrome.storage.local.set(data)
                .then(() => {
                    chrome.action.setBadgeText({
                        text: request.total.toString(),
                        tabId: sender.tab.id
                    });
                });
        });
});

// Clear Cache
chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(tabId => {
    chrome.storage.local.get('counts')
        .then(data => {
            if (data.counts) delete data.counts['tab' + tabId];
            chrome.storage.local.set(data);
        });
});
```

**content.js:**

```
if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
        pageFunction();
    } else {
        window.addEventListener('load', pageFunction);
    }

function pageFunction(){
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img").length;
var iFrames = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe").length;

var total = images + iFrames;

var counts = {images, iFrames, total};

chrome.storage.local.set(counts);   // persist data
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(counts); // send to background
}
```

**popup.js**

```
chrome.tabs.query({
        active: true,
        currentWindow: true
    })
    .then(tabs => {
        var tab = tabs[0];
        chrome.storage.local.get('counts')
            .then(data => {
             var x = data.counts[tab.id];
    
document.getElementById("iFrameHTML").innerHTML = x.iFrames;
document.getElementById("iFrameHTML").innerHTML = x.images;
document.getElementById("iFrameHTML").innerHTML = x.total;

    });  
    });
```

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="Chart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css">
    
</head>
  
<body>

<p id ="totalHTML">Total Score</p>
<p id ="imgHTML">Image Score</p>
<p id ="iFrameHTML">iFrame Score</p>

<script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "action":{
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "/images/16.png",
            "32": "/images/32.png",
            "48": "/images/48.png",
            "128": "/images/128.png"
        }
    },
  "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "*://*/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "content.js"
            ]
        }
      ],
  "options_page": "popup.html", 
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
},
  "permissions": [
      "storage", 
    "activeTab" 
],
"icons": {
      "16": "/images/16.png",
      "32": "/images/32.png",
      "48": "/images/48.png",
      "128": "/images/128.png"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what ended up working for me. I want to share encase it can help somebody else. This will ensure that each popup displays the data for a specific tab.

**Background.js:**

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(details => {
  chrome.storage.local.clear();
});
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, tab)=> {
    if (tab.status == "complete") {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {start: true});
    }
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender) => {
    //console.log(request)
    chrome.storage.local.set({["tab"+sender.tab.id]:request}); 
    chrome.storage.local.get("tab"+sender.tab.id).then(dat => {
        chrome.action.setBadgeText({
            text: request.total+ "",
            tabId: sender.tab.id
        });
    });
});

// Clear Cache
chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(tabId => {
    chrome.storage.local.get('tab'+tabId).then(data => {
        delete data['tab' + tabId];
    });
});
```

**content.js:**

```
function pageFunction(){
    
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img").length;
var iFrames = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe").length;

var total = images + iFrames;

var counts = {images, iFrames, total};


chrome.runtime.sendMessage(counts); // send to background  

}
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(msg=> {
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
        pageFunction();
    } else {
        window.addEventListener('load', pageFunction);
    }
});
```

**popup.js**

```
chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true,currentWindow: true
}).then(tabs => {
    var tab = tabs[0];
    chrome.storage.local.get("tab"+tab.id).then(data => {
           try{
            var x = data["tab"+tab.id];
            document.getElementById("iFrameHTML").innerHTML = x.iFrames;
            document.getElementById("imgHTML").innerHTML = x.images;
            document.getElementById("totalHTML").innerHTML = x.total;
         }catch(e) {
        }
        
    });
});
```

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="Chart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css">
    
</head>
  
<body>

<p id ="totalHTML">Total Score</p>
<p id ="imgHTML">Image Score</p>
<p id ="iFrameHTML">iFrame Score</p>

<script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "action":{
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "/images/16.png",
            "32": "/images/32.png",
            "48": "/images/48.png",
            "128": "/images/128.png"
        }
    },
  "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "*://*/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "content.js"
            ]
        }
      ],
  "options_page": "popup.html", 
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
},
  "permissions": [
      "storage", 
    "activeTab" 
],
"icons": {
      "16": "/images/16.png",
      "32": "/images/32.png",
      "48": "/images/48.png",
      "128": "/images/128.png"
    }
}
```